# Send data from .net application to electron app

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, electron

We need to send some data from my .net WinForm application to electron application. As both applications are independent we need to open some TCP port in nodejs project and send data on same port from my .net app but here I am stuck between how I can send the data from my .net app.

Can someone please provide an example or documentation which would help me to resolve my issue.

I tried to achieve it using [node-ipc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ipc) package but no luck.

- Node version: 8.11.1
- npm version: 5.6.0
- electron version: 1.7.10

Answer (score 1):

I had the same roadblock in my application.

You could use the mechanism of Inter process communication, use socket.io and create a socket to act as a communication link between the two process.

You'll have to create a socket listener in your your electron app, the following snippet worked for me

```
var serverSocket = require('net');
var webFrame = require('electron').webFrame;    
function createSocketListener(PORT, HOST) {
        serverSocket.createServer(function (socket) {
            var buffer = "";
            console.log('CONNECTED: ' + socket.remoteAddress + ':' + socket.remotePort);
            socket.on('data', function (data) {
                buffer = data;
            });
            socket.on('close', function (data) {
                // closed connection
                console.log('DATA : ' + buffer);
            });
        }).listen(PORT, HOST);
    }
```

You can then create your custom protocol and send the data from your .net application to the electron application by connecting to the same socket.

You can look into the following link for further control and optimization.
https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main